# Distributing with additions and multiplications.

Tags: number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

I'm trying to find the Bézout coefficients for $\gcd(68, 92)$, but I'm having trouble simplifying the substitutions from the results of the Euclidean algorithm.

I am currently stuck at:
$$4 = 24 - 1 \times (68 - 2 \times 24)$$
How does $(24 - 1)$ distribute when multiplied with $(68 - 2 \times 24)$?

Comment: There isn't any $(24-1)$; there is $(24)-(1(68-(2\cdot24)))$.

Comment: distribute the -1 to 68 and -2
you need to keep going until you see nothing but 68 and 92

Answer (score 1):

$92=1\cdot 68 + 24$

$68=2\cdot 24 + 20$

$24=1\cdot 20 + 4$

$20=5\cdot 4 + 0$

=> $\gcd(68,92)=4$

=> $\,4=24-1\cdot 20=24-1\cdot (68-2\cdot 24)=3\cdot 24-1\cdot 68$

$ => 4 =3\cdot(92-1\cdot 68)-1\cdot 68=3\cdot 92-4\cdot 68$

Result: $\,\,4=3\cdot 92-4\cdot 68$